# load view from library Android

Tags: android, static-libraries

How can I load a webview from a external Android library and to some work on that.

The code needs to be private in the library.

I want others developers to call a payment form loaded from a uiwebview which is located in a library and also setting event listeners for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either:

- Have a method that returns a `View` (in this case, the `WebView`) that users of your library have to add to their UI, or
- Have a method that takes a `ViewGroup`, into which you add your `WebView`.

I would strongly recommend the former approach, so the user of your library has greater control over the sizing and positioning of your `View` relative to other things.

That being said, if this is a payment form, you may be better served showing your `WebView` in a dedicated activity, or a dedicated fragment, or in a `Dialog`, rather than expecting the developer to cram your `WebView` into the existing UI.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Create your widget, make it `final` (so no one can extend it), and compile in `Library` module. `Library` module will generate .jar file with your widget component.

**EDIT:** How to create `Android Library` project in [Intellij Idea](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/sharing-android-source-code-and-resources-using-library-projects.html#d173186e465),
[Eclipse](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html)

Comment: Can I find an example somewhere ?